# What is resultdata here

Tags: jquery

```
$('#register').on('click',function(){               

    $.ajax({
        url: combochart.php,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resultdata){
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(resultdata));                                                   
        }
    });     
});
```

what is resultdata here , if my output which i want to display is come through a 
    function drawVisualization() on combochart.php page then how i call that function through ajax here plz help me

Comment: The code above is to call combochart.php via AJAX, so what's not actually working for you?

Comment: resultdata is the result returned by combochart.php . Have you ever performed an AJAX request or have you an idea of what it is? you look quite confused...

Comment: so how will you call drawVisualization() on combochart.php if you call directly from browser address bar ????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427985/make-jquery-ajax-call-to-specific-php-functions

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#register').on('click',function(){               

$.ajax({
    url: 'combochart.php',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resultdata){
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization(resultdata));                                                   
    }
});     
});
```

`url` is a string and must have quotes.

`resultdata` is the response from the server, in your case combochart.php. The response is usually printed by the PHP script using a `echo` statement, or may be a json dump.